# Parse responseJSON to ObjectMapper

Tags: swift4, alamofire, objectmapper

I'm currently making a migration from Android to iOS, better said Java to Swift, I got a generic response in JSON, but I'm not able to use it as an object and show it in the storyboard. I'm really new to Swift so I've been stuck for a while.

I've tried ObjectMapper and also JSON decode with no result at all.

I declared this response as I used in Java(Android)

```
class ResponseObjectMapper<T,R>: Mappable where T: Mappable,R:Mappable{

var data:T?
var message:String!
var error:R?

required init?(_ map: Map) {
    self.mapping(map: map)
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    data          <- map["data"]
    message          <- map["message"]
    error          <- map["error"]
}
}

class UserMapper :Mappable{
var email:String?
var fullName:String?
var id:CLong?
var phoneNumber:String?
var token:CLong?

required init?(_ map: Map) {
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    email <- map["email"]
    fullName <- map["fullName"]
    id <- map["id"]
    phoneNumber <- map["phoneNumber"]
    token <- map["token"]
    phoneNumber <- map["phoneNumber"]
}
}
```

In my Android project I use the Gson dependency and I was able to use my JSON as an object

```
class ErrorMapper:Mappable{

var message:String?
var code:Int?

required init?(_ map: Map) {
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    message          <- map["message"]
    code          <- map["code"]
}

}
```

This is the *Alamofire* that gave me the JSON.

```
func login(params: [String:Any]){Alamofire.request
("http://192.168.0.192:8081/SpringBoot/user/login", method: .post, 
parameters: params,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: 
headers).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:

                let response = Mapper<ResponseObjectMapper<UserMapper,ErrorMapper>>.map(JSONString: response.data)


                break
            case .failure(let error):

                print(error)
            }
        }
}
```

If I print the response with print(response) I got

```
SUCCESS: {
data =     {
    email = "vpozo@montran.com";
    fullName = "Victor Pozo";
    id = 6;
    phoneNumber = 099963212;
    token = 6;
};
error = "<null>";
message = SUCCESS;
}
```

and if I use this code I can got a result with key and value but I don't know how to use it as an object

```
if let result = response.result.value {
                    let responseDict = result as! [String : Any]
                    print(responseDict["data"])
                }
```

console:

```
Optional({
email = "vpozo@gmail.com";
fullName = "Victor Pozo";
id = 6;
phoneNumber = 099963212;
token = 6;
})
```

I would like to use it in an Object, like `user.token` in a View Controller, probably I'm really confused, trying to map with generic attributes.

```
Type 'ResponseObjectMapper<UserMapper, ErrorMapper>' does not conform to protocol 'BaseMappable'
```

Comment: Hi Victor... Do check out the SwiftyJSON library for swift. It helps you get a JSON response as an object directly.

Here is the link => https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Hi @CedanMisquith, I've been trying some dependencies in cocoapods, intalled Swifty but I don't get how to use the data key and value an then parse it as an object. I'll try it again thanks.

Comment: I can definetly help you out with code. It’s quite simple I will use your JSON for example and post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you will need a Network Manager which uses Alamofire to make all your requests. I have made generalized one that looks something like this. You can modify it as you want.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class NetworkHandler: NSObject {

let publicURLHeaders : HTTPHeaders = [
    "Content-type" : "application/json"
]

let privateURLHeaders : HTTPHeaders = [
    "Content-type" : "application/json",
    "Authorization" : ""
]

enum RequestType {
    case publicURL
    case privateURL
}

func createNetworkRequestWithJSON(urlString : String , prametres : [String : Any], type : RequestType, completion:@escaping(JSON) -> Void) {

    let internetIsReachable = NetworkReachabilityManager()?.isReachable ?? false
    if !internetIsReachable {
        AlertViewManager.sharedInstance.showAlertFromWindow(title: "", message: "No internet connectivity.")
    } else {
        switch type {
        case .publicURL :
            commonRequest(urlString: baseURL+urlString, parameters: prametres, completion: completion, headers: publicURLHeaders)
            break
        case .privateURL:
            commonRequest(urlString: baseURL+urlString, parameters: prametres, completion: completion, headers: privateURLHeaders)
            break
        }
    }
}

func commonRequest(urlString : String, parameters : [String : Any], completion : @escaping (JSON) -> Void , headers : HTTPHeaders){

    print("urlString:"+urlString)
    print("headers:")
    print(headers)
    print("parameters:")
    print(parameters)

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpHeaders = headers
    request.timeoutInterval = 10
    let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

    let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    if let json = json {
        print("parameters:")
        print(json)
    }

    request.httpBody = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    let alamoRequest = AF.request(request as URLRequestConvertible)
    alamoRequest.validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    alamoRequest.responseJSON{ response in
        print(response.response?.statusCode as Any )
        if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
            switch(status){
            case 201:
                print("example success")
                SwiftLoader.hide()
            case 200 :
                if let json = response.value {
                    let jsonObject = JSON(json)
                    completion(jsonObject)
                }
            default:
                SwiftLoader.hide()
                print("error with response status: \(status)")
            }
        }else{
            let jsonObject = JSON()
            completion(jsonObject)
            SwiftLoader.hide()
        }
    }
}
}
```

After this when ever you need to make a request you can use this function. This will take in parameters if any needed and once the request is complete it will execute a call back function in which you can handle the response. The response here will be of SWIFTYJSON format.

```
func makeNetworkRequest(){
    let networkHandler = NetworkHandler()
    var parameters : [String:String] = [:]
    parameters["email"] = usernameTextField.text
    parameters["pass"] = passwordTextField.text
    networkHandler.createNetworkRequestWithJSON(urlString: "http://192.168.0.192:8081/SpringBoot/user/login", prametres: parameters, type: .publicURL, completion: self.handleResponseForRequest)
}


func handleResponseForRequest(response: JSON){
    if let message = response["message"].string{
        if message == "SUCCESS"{

            if let email = response["data"]["email"].string{
                //Do something with email.
            }

            if let fullName = response["data"]["fullName"].string{
                //Do something with fullName.
            }

            if let id = response["data"]["id"].int{
                //Do something with id.
            }

            if let phoneNumber = response["data"]["phoneNumber"].int64{
                //Do something with phoneNumber.
            }

            if let token = response["data"]["token"].int{
                //Do something with token.
            }
        }else{
            //Error
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: I aprreciate your help @CedanMisquith, but I have a doubt with the manager, I got this error.


    Value of type 'URLRequest' has no member 'httpHeaders'

on

    request.httpHeaders = headers

now it worked with is ok?

    .allHTTPHEaderFields

one more question so I'm using a click button on my view controller, then it calls a function like makeNetworkRequest, how should I call a new controller and use that data, in Android I use a bundle, but how I can use the data in a new view in swift, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: So I think the headers error is happening coz you got the latest version of Alamofire library and the syntax has changed. So I think changing the syntax is the right thing you did. Now tell me if i am right ... you want to move to a new view controller after a successful response from the server request and then you want to use that response in the new viewcontroller right ???

Comment: Ok so are you stuck anywhere now ?? Were you able to access the data in your new view controller  ??

Comment: SwiftyJSON makes everything, I was able to parse as an object using a struct with a constructor  `init(userView:JSON){
        self.fullName = userView["fullName"].stringValue ` and parse it as an object using `completion:@escaping(JSON) -> Void` and then in the viewController `let user=UserObject(userObject:userJson)`. The answer of your question is yes I want to show the user information and how do I keep the token to use it in other request. Also I need iterate accounts to use it on a pickerview
`let jsonAccounts = response["data"]` gives me 2 accounts. BTW **Thanks a lot for your help**

Comment: So for storing the `Token` you can look into `UserDefaults`. This will help you store the token in your app under a `key` name and you can retrieve it anywhere in your app using that `key`.